# Using C# How to detect if Windows Installer 4.5 is Installed

Tags: c#, .net, windows, installation

I am trying to figure out the most efficient way to determine if Windows Installer 4.5 is installed on a machine.

I have a 2.0 application (cannot convert at this time to 3.5) and we are upgrading from MSDE to SQL 2008 Express. One of the requirements of 2008 Express is that Windows Installer 4.5 is installed on the machine. This application is deployed globally to machines both on and off of an internal network.

I would prefer to run a batch file or C# code to determine the installer version.

Please let me know your recommended methods and provide some code (or links to code).

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can read the file version of the `msi.dll` library in the system directory:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

public bool IsWindowsInstaller45Installed()
{
    FileVersionInfo info;
    string fileName = Path.Combine(Environment.SystemDirectory, "msi.dll");
    try {
        info = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(fileName);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException) {
        return false;
    }

    return (info.FileMajorPart > 4
            || info.FileMajorPart == 4 && info.FileMinorPart >= 5);
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the quick response. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Check the version of the MSI.DLL file that's in your System32 directory.

You should be able to use [GetFileVersionInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms647003%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [GetFileVersionInfoEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969434%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to get out the version number.

This MSDN article has some sample code: [Unsafe Code Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288474%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Like Ho1 said, you can go by the version of MSI.dll in System32 but you don't need to P/Invoke you can use the FileVersionInfo class found in System.Diagnostics.

Comment: Though if you take away the pinvoke, you're taking away most of the fun :)

Comment: No, Frederic took away all the fun by giving the OP a copy and paste answer.   I like to answer questions not do homework.